# VB.net Structures and Lists

Tags: vb.net, structure, runtime-error

Let's say I have a structure

```
Structure Test
    Public Names as List(Of Strings)
End Structure
```

I receive the error

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred
```

So I stepped into the code and it errors every time I get to adding a string to Names

Example:

```
Dim a as new Test
Dim b = 1
While b < 2
    if b = 1 then
        a.add("Cheese")
    End If
    b += 1
End While
```

An error would throw at `a.add("Cheese")`

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Structure Test
    Public Sub New()
       Me.Names = New List(Of String)
    End Sub 
    Public Names as List(Of Strings) 
End Structure
```

You could Initialize the Names List within the constructor if the desired behavior is when you New Up the structure that you can just start adding items to the list.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2hkbth2a(v=vs.80).aspx/css

Answer (score 2):

You need a new `List` before you can call the `.Add` method; also, you are calling the add method on your new structure instead of its List member.

```
Dim a as new Test
a.Names = New List(Of String)
Dim b = 1
While b < 2
    if b = 1 then
        a.Names.Add("Cheese")
    End If
    b += 1
End While
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Names As New List(Of String)
```

Or

```
Public Names As List(Of String)
..
Names = New List(Of String)
```

All you have done so far is declare that Names will be a list of string if and when you get around to creating an instance of it...which you never did.  Also it is `String` not `Strings`

Comment: usually the structure would have the responsibility of newing up the list

Comment: I tried the first option with 
    Public Names As New List(Of String)
I get the error 
A non shared member in a structure can not be declared New

On the second part Names = New List(Of String) 
Where would i put that using my exsample